# How to fix utf-8 in database

Tags: php, mysql

I tried my project on localhost and it works well, there are no errors.

But when I upload my project to a real server (bought server)

and when inserting a value to database (phpMyAdmin) it shows me an unknown language.

For example:

In page "signup" when user writes name and password using Arabic language it inserts in database like "Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯"

This images show unknown language
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2790/cj4yefwmguzi85ozg.jpg?size_id=8

But in same page if user write name and password "using English language" its insert in database correctly

So how can I fix this? If user write in `<input>` using other language like Arabic language, insert it in database correctly

Note: when user write name and password using Arabic language and in database show like "Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯", and when I display it from database to my website it shows me he value correctly and there no errors.

My question: how can I fix encoding/charsets in database.

This is my code:

```
$insert_c = "INSERT INTO customers(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')";

$run_c = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_c);
```

And sorry about my English language, I'm use Google translate

This image show utf8
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/dfaf/k2i263014e14szgzg.jpg?size_id=8

Comment: Hi, try to set utf8 as charset for your mysqli_connection. See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @DS87 Thank you my friend.

Comment: Is it the answer?

Comment: Yup Thanks @DS87